# How to remove border in WPF Visual Studio designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, window, border

When I'm trying to design an interface in the designer on Visual Studio, a white border surrounds all of my windows.

When I set a background for the window, it will be contained within this white border, but when it runs, the background will expand into the white area from the designer. All major outer margins are set to 0.

This makes it impossible to design anything due to the IDE changing my layout when it compiles.

How do I remove this border?

[edit] Sorry, i forgot a sample of the code!, here's the top half the outer most xml minus the resources

```
<Window x:Class="BuildSaverAlpha4.Main_Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Main_Window" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="False" WindowStyle="None" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Activated="Window_Activated" Deactivated="Window_Deactivated" Closing="Window_Closing" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="562" Width="911" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0">


<Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Name="outerGrid" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid Height="41" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,20,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="872" Background="#5DFF0000">
    </Grid>
    <Grid Background="#5DFF0000" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,72,0,0" Name="grid2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="872"></Grid>
    <TabControl Name="tabControl1" Margin="12,0,0,38" Background="{x:Null}"
```

[image]

Comment: You should really post some XAML, dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears to be an issue with VS 2008, and 2010:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/69cff97e-52d6-4130-8713-daf130580f54

If you use Expression, then selecting WindowStyle=None will drop the border correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your control isn't filling the window.  Without seeing the xaml it's hard to post the code to fix this but if it's a grid then make sure there are no fixed width or height in the markup.  Something else to look at for other controls are setting Horizontalalignment and verticalalignment to "Stretch". If you can post the XAML of this window then I'll try and correct for you.